# How do I calculate sum of values in a column with different units?

Tags: sum, libreoffice-calc

```
Date            From            To              Upload      Download    Total
03/12/15        00:53:52        01:53:52        407 KB      4.55 MB     4.94 MB
                01:53:51        02:53:51        68.33 MB    1.60 GB     1.66 GB
                02:53:51        03:53:51        95.39 MB    2.01 GB     2.10 GB
                03:53:50        04:53:50        0 KB        208 KB      209 KB
                04:53:50        05:53:50        0 KB        10 KB       11 KB
                05:53:49        06:53:49        0 KB        7 KB        7 KB
                06:53:49        07:53:49        370 KB      756 KB      1.10 MB
                07:53:48        08:53:48        2.69 MB     64.05 MB    66.74 MB
```

I have this data in a spreadsheet. The last column contains total data usage in an hour. I would like to add all data used in a day in GB. The total data usage as you can see varies. It has KB, MB and GB.

How can I do it in LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What did you try already? What's the "real" content of the "total data usage" columns - text or numbers (or numbers and text, effectively resulting into string values = text) ? How do you want to convert between (e.g.) MG and GB - 1024=1 or 1000=1 (decimal - easier, but unprecise)?

Answer (score 1):

Converting all the totals into kilobytes and then summing the column of kilobytes seems like the most straightforward method.

Assuming your "Total" column is column F, and the entries in this column are text (and not numbers formatted to have the varies byte size indicators on the end), this formula will convert GB into KB:

```
=IF(RIGHT(F2,2)="GB",1048576*VALUE(LEFT(F2,LEN(F2)-3)),"Not a GB entry")
```

The IF function takes parameters `IF(Test is True, Then Do This, Else Do That)`.  In this case we are telling Calc:

- IF the right two characters in this string are "GB"
- THEN take the left characters minus three, convert the string into a number with VALUE, and multiply by 1,045,576
- ELSE give an error message

You want to handle GB, MB, and KB, which requires nested IF statements like so:

```
=IF(RIGHT(F2,2)="GB",1048576*VALUE(LEFT(F2,LEN(F2)-3)),IF(RIGHT(F2,2)="MB",1024*VALUE(LEFT(F2,LEN(F2)-3)),IF(RIGHT(F2,2)="KB",VALUE(LEFT(F2,LEN(F2)-3)),"No byte size given")))
```

Copy and paste the formula down however long your column is.  Then SUM over the calculated KB values.

Comment: Why you used comma separate "," between function parameters? In Libre/Open Office must using dot-comma ";".

Answer (score 0):

This is correct formula for G, M, K suffixies, value getting from B2 cell:

```
=IF(RIGHT(B2;1)="G";1048576*VALUE(LEFT(B2;LEN(B2)-1));IF(RIGHT(B2;1)="M";1024*VALUE(LEFT(B2;LEN(B2)-1));IF(RIGHT(B2;1)="K";VALUE(LEFT(B2;LEN(B2)-1));"No byte size given")))
```